# How to pivot this using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm totally new to python/pandas so please bear with me.

I have been trying for what seems like an eternity to rearrange my dataframe (see the numbers beside in/out...). I have read several answers to what seem like similar questions on stack overflow but I can't get anything to work for me.

Initially I had a table that looked like this:[intial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWsjO.png)

I want to make it look like this (but with the actual dates and values):

```
company--date--date--date--date

ebay--------val-----val---val----val

amazon----val-----val---val----val
```

Initially I thought I could use df.pivot but then I didn't know what to put for index= because I didn't have a name for the columns. So I figured out how to give them a name using

```
df.columns.names = 'Company'
```

Now I have a table like this:[table as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4DPQ.png)

Based on other answers I've seen on this site I tried again to use df.pivot 1.with index = 'Company' and I get KeyError: 'Company'
2.also with index = ['Company'] also get KeyError: 'Company'

Can anyone tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: dont use links to pictures please.

Comment: It said I wasn't able to post pictures yet and have to use links. I assume this is because I'm new here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/6361531

Comment: You're passing 'Company' as the name of the column _index_, not the column name. In this case, your column names are already 'Ebay' and 'Amazon', which is why you get the "keyError". If you want to see or set the names of the columns, you can use `print(df.columns)` or `df.columns = ['Col1','Col2']`

Comment: @G.Anderson I was trying to make the index of my pivoted dataframe the companies. I thought that by saying `df.pivot(index='Company')` I would achieve that. Am I totally misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Helen, better you can try as `df.set_index('Company')` if you want Company as an index though.

Comment: Changing the `.name` attribute of an element doesn't do the same thing as changing the element itself. If you want to change the actual index, you can use `pd.set_index()`. However, that won't do exactly what you're trying to do. In one of the answers below, @jeevan kumar shows a solution using `transpose`

Comment: You can change the index using set_index however,there is better way with transpose (df.T) method in pandas that's mend for it as already explained  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean 'transpose' not 'pivot'. Can you please try doing the following?
`df1.T`. Full example below from [pandas.DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

setup:

```
d1 = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1
```

output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

code:

```
df1.T # or df1.transpose()
```

output:

```
      0  1
col1  1  2
col2  3  4
```